# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

```
btnImport()
{
    GetVideoLists();
}

public static void GetVideoLists(string listFile)
{
    videoList = new List<videoInfo>();
    string[] videoArr = File.ReadAllLines(listFile);
    foreach (string videoInfo in videoArr)
    {
        string[] info = videoInfo.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        // here i get error
        videoInfo tempInfo = new videoInfo(info[0].Trim(), info[1].Trim()); 
        if (CheckVideoUrl(tempInfo.videoUrl))
        {
            videoList.Add(tempInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure each line of videoArr has a value?

Comment: [Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading **the SO Tour**. it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Probably just an item of videoArr that do not contain a `,` so the `info[1]` does not exist.

Comment: whenever you try to access any element in an array you can avoid this problem by making sure that the particular element exist by checking whether the index number which you access is less than the length of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've assumed *every* line in your file has at least one comma in it:

```
string[] info = videoInfo.Split(new char[] { ',' });
videoInfo tempInfo = new videoInfo(info[0].Trim(), info[1].Trim());
```

This will fail if there is no comma in `videoInfo`. To fix this, use:

```
string[] info = videoInfo.Split(new char[] { ',' });
if (info.Length >= 1)
{
    videoInfo tempInfo = new videoInfo(info[0].Trim(), info[1].Trim());
    ...
}
```

Or

```
string[] info = videoInfo.Split(new char[] { ',' });
if (info.Length < 1)
    continue;

videoInfo tempInfo = new videoInfo(info[0].Trim(), info[1].Trim());
...
```

Comment: thx.. for help great. i don't check it clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You are splitting by comma and the string may not contain a comma hence info[1] is not there.

Show us the value of videoinfo. if it contains say `"test, test2"` then it will be fine. as you are splitting by comma you get position [0] and [1].